# Is it possible for villagers to trade horse armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With the latest 1.6.2 edition with the horse update I wanted to check some things out. I know you can get saddles from a villager trade but can you get horse armor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

[Villagers don't trade horse armour.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#Possible_offers)

But if you want to have a renewable source of horse armour, I'm quite happy with the mod [Horse Accessories](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1170158-162-morphcore-creepersnocreeping-batsdropleather-horseaccessories-zombietweak-witchspawn-rebelsnowmen-villagerspawn-august-2013/), which adds (appropriately expensive) craftable horse armour.

Comment: where do i put the mod so it can work?

Comment: Install instructions are in the post linked to. Reading the whole post is recommended.